# Firestore merge 2 queries with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, stream, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make 2 queries to Firestore and merge the results into one in order to simulate a Firestore OR query.

I segmented my code according to the bloc pattern.

```dart
///private method to zip QuerySnapshot streams
Stream<List<QuerySnapshot>> _combineStreams(String userId) {

    var stream1 = todosCollection
        .where("owners", arrayContains: userId)
        .snapshots();

    var stream2 = todosCollection
      .where("contributors", arrayContains: userId)
      .snapshots();

    return StreamZip(([stream1, stream2])).asBroadcastStream();
  }

///exposed method to be consumed by repository
Stream<List<Todo>> todos(String userId) {

    var controller = StreamController<List<Todo>>();

    _combineStreams(userId).listen((snapshots) {

      List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = List<DocumentSnapshot>();

      snapshots.forEach((snapshot) {
        documents.addAll(snapshot.documents);
      });

      final todos = documents.map((doc) {
        return Todo.fromEntity(TodoEntity.fromSnapshot(doc));
      }).toList();

      controller.add(todos);
    });

    return controller.stream;
  }
```

In my bloc I have the following code that should update my view accordingly my database state but it's not working. The database insertion work but the view doesn't refresh and I don't know why.

```dart
_gardensSubscription?.cancel();
    _gardensSubscription = _dataRepository.gardens(event.userId).listen(
          (gardens) {
        dispatch(
          GardensUpdated(gardens),
        );
      },
    );
```

I am not very confortable with Stream and particularly with StreamController process. Is it possible to do this task more easily?

Answer (score 0):

Time to use the great powers of RxDart: https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart

You can't do all types of streams transformations with this lib.

For example, you can use the merge operators to achieve exactly what you want

Comment: I already try to use RxDart but I lack informations. Do you have some working code or some other tips to help me ? Thks